# Highcharts - apply gradient on custom colors

Tags: highcharts

This is my data model:

```
data = [{y: 123, color: "#FF7600"}, {y: 321, color: "#00FFE3"}, {y: 213,color: "#444444"}]
```

Then the series is added to a pie chart:

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: /pie-chart, params: {})
    .success(function (data) {
        chart.addSeries({
        type: 'pie',
        data: data
    })
});
```

Here's the official highcharts demo: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-gradient
It loops through data, read colors, creates color array and uses this array when drawing chart.
But i'm thinking about solution which avoids extracting colors from JSON.
Any idea? Thanks a lot.

**Edited, solved**

Gave it up :).
 
I ended up creating color arrays as described in highcharts demo.
It works well.

```
// Get colors from received data, create color array, 
var colors = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data[0].series.length; i++) {
    colors.push(data[0].series[i].color);
    // Delete original colors, so that new radialized are used
    delete(data[i].color);
}

// Use color array and radialize each color
Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(colors, function(color) {
    return {
        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0 },
            stops: [
                [0, color],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
            ]
        };
    });
```

Comment: "Data" is in fact plural. The correct usage is "data are" not "data is," a single piece of data is a "datum." Although we never use it that way.

Comment: @Jara so problem is solved?

Comment: @Sebatian. Just the right english grammar of my inquiry is fixed. Still didn't find how to apply gradient when custom color is one of the data object parameter. Your help  would be deeply appreciated. (jsfiddle example would be the greatest).

Answer (score 0):

The solution mentioned above sets the colors in the global defaults.  This is okay if you have only one chart, but if you have multiple it can be problematic, as the colors will apply for all charts.

You can colorize this on the individual chart level by remapping the colors just in the local data array.  Here is what I do for my pie charts.

chartData is an array of data like:

```js
[
    {
        "color": "#01080f", 
        "name": "No Status", 
        "y": 8570
    }, 
    {
        "color": "#1A942C", 
        "name": "Deployed", 
        "y": 27952
    }, 
    ...
    {
        "color": "#f36e20", 
        "name": "Out of sync", 
        "y": 241
    }
]
```

In my javascript code it is retrieved from the server and applied to the Highcharts object's series.data element.

Just manipulate that data element before you add it to the highcharts object.

```js
// Retrieve your chart data
$.getJSON('/api/endpoint/policystatus', function (chartData) {

    // Function replaces flat colors with gradients
    function colorizeData(data) {
        data.color = {
            radialGradient: {cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7},
            stops: [
                [0, data.color],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(data.color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
            ]
        };
    }

    // Call the function for each element in the retrieved data
    chartData.forEach(colorizeData);

    // Continue on to build your chart
    $('#pie-general-status').highcharts({
    // ....
```

The above 'colorizeData' takes the chart data input, looks for the 'color' element, then replaces it with the Highcharts gradient based on the same color.

Note that you must use hex or RGB values; it will not work with colors defined as the words 'green' or 'blue'.